# Refactoring a userscript to use javascript modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, requirejs, userscripts

I'm working on a userscript - in particular [this userscript](https://github.com/josh-/Hubski-Enhancement-Suite/blob/master/hubski_enhancement_suite.user.js) - which has been designed to encapsulate functionality in modules. In order to be able to do some automated testing I would like to split the modules into their own files and use node.js's module exporting and require functions to combine into one file for use in Greasemonkey or simple browser extensions.

My first thought was to just copy the modules into their own files as such

**module.js**

```
var exportedModule = (function (){  
    var Module = {  
        // public functions and members  
    };  

    //private functions and members  

    return Module;  
}());  

module.exports = exports = exportedModule;
```

And then have a central file that requires each of these modules, perhaps compiling them with something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

**script.js**

```
var importedModule = require(./module);

importedModule.init();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Note that [`require` is a keyword](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require) in userscripts.  The old title was a bit confusing. ... PS:  You should be using `@require` for this kind of thing AMAP, but it's only fully supported in Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey, at the moment.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for the clarification edit. We were using require but are working to bundle this script into browser extensions. I'm mostly looking into things like nodejs and requirejs for ways to improve our development process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you would be better off using [Requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org/), which uses AMD style modules and is inherently more browser friendly.  Node commonjs-style modules are synchronous and do not fit the browser model very well.

Of course, using requirejs will change your scripts a bit.

Comment: Yes. And I would like to add the the common.js style module system is actually horrible. Even Ryan Dahl (The maker of node.js) regrets his decision.

Comment: Really?  I actually quite like it when it is used appropriately. IMO the main problem is its lack of compatibility with AMD, making it tricky to uses scripts both on the client and server.  But...I don't want to get into a religious war here. :-)  Can you provide a link?

Comment: There you go: http://bostinno.com/2011/01/31/node-js-interview-4-questions-with-creator-ryan-dahl/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I think that what Dahl is really saying (I am now putting words in his mouth) is that there is no "great" module systems. They are all kind of ok when used appropriately. The biggest tragedy is that they don't work together.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) makes it easy:

```
browserify src/my.user.js -o dist/my.user.js
```

The metadata in the source file may get moved, but it's still parsed correctly (by Greasemonkey at least).

For a more complex example which compiles various assets, including CSS and images, see [here](https://github.com/cletusc/Userscript--Twitch-Chat-Emotes).

Comment: I installed node.js and browserify, and when I run the above command, I get the error "SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (57:0) while parsing". What I my doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnSmith The question is about using CommonJS (i.e. `require`), which is what Browserify supports out of the box. To transpile ESM (i.e. `import` and `export`), you'll need to use the [Babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify) (or [TypeScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify)) plugin.

Comment: For future reference, where does it specify about CommonJS only? Rereading this question, it still sounds exactly like what I was trying to do. Is there a tag somewhere that I'm not seeing? BTW I did pursue this on my own far enough to try to install Babel, which led me down a rabbit hole of errors probably not germane to this discussion, and I abandoned the idea of trying to do this.

Comment: @JohnSmith To answer your question: 1. The question is from 2013. ECMAScript modules (ESM) and the `import` syntax was only standardized in 2015. 2. The code in question uses the Node module loading system using `require()` calls. 3. It talks about NodeJS which is incompatible with ESM in its standard runtime (per 2022). You need to explicitly enable it using a different file extension or transpile your code. 

So it's pretty clear.